# How can I beat the enemies on the castle stairs?

Tags: candy-box

How do I beat the ghosts on the castle stairs? Can I just avoid them?

I have Sword of Flames level 7 and 350hp, but I always lose. I haven't tried using health potions. What should I do to get past this area?

Comment: Ok, managed to parse the question using the wiki but, having only played Candy Box 2 I can't be of much help.

Answer (score 2):

Ghosts halve human HP on each hit. So the answer is to knock it with something that's not human! Use an imp scroll; imps can't take damage from ghosts. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a sword of summoning level 4, which if you use some health potions, you should get through the level.